# With VirtueMart, can I offset all the product prices by a percentage or amount based on currency?

Tags: php, sql, joomla, shopping-cart, virtuemart

We are in the middle of building a shopping cart and are using Virtuemart. All our prices are in Canadian dollars; however, we buy from American suppliers. If the dollar value changes, we would like to change the prices for all products based on a percentage or offset to compensate for the daily currency. Is this difficult or possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a this currency converter that adjusts prices based on the current exchange rate - http://extensions.virtuemart.net/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=6&sobi2Id=93